# Tag cleanup for July 2013

Tags: support, retag-request, clean-up

Following tags are meta tags ([what is this?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)), need to be removed/made synonyms

- [themes](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/themes) - needs disambiguation
- [tags](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags)
- [sorting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting)
- [list](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list) - needs disambiguation
- [audio](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio)
- [website](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website)
- [webservice](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webservice)

---

### Important

Do not flag/vote to close for migration; many of them are too old, too highly upvoted, just plain crap, or out of scope according to their FAQ.

**Remember, we don't migrate crap.**

In this case, as mentioned above, cast your vote for closure and/or deletion and also flag for moderator attention and we'll review it.

#### Pro-tip #1

If you are removing tags from a massive number of questions, it's better to go to the last question on the last page of all questions with that tag and work your way backwards. This prevents you from having to deal with the cache not reflecting your edits on the question list combined with browser-cache issues.

If you haven't visited most of these questions, you'll know what you changed because the link for the question will have a different color.

#### Pro-tip #2

**Please edit in small batches & be mindful of front-page flooding** - we don't want the entire front page to be filled with edits of old questions. This is especially important for webapps since the rate of new questions is low.

Please edit the question and add/remove each tag as necessary and when done.

Comment: So actually the first part of your question has to do with NOT using meta tags in [main] and the second part gives instructions on how to handle possible bulk re-tagging questions?

Comment: @Jacob yes, that would be right :)

Comment: Did you add the [tag:online] tag as well?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra yes, will keep adding as & when I find them

Comment: `services` tag is now empty, removed. Updated title to May since the last two still have plenty.

Comment: `alternative` appears to be a close relative of our favorite `webapp-rec` (a number are even tagged with both). Should it be a synonym?

Comment: @JohnC Yes, a synonym is better - I just went ahead and merged it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

These tags are now history:

- [programming](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming)
- [online](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online)
- [settings](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/settings)
- [server](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server)

Good work team!

Comment: I have added few more, if you're interested ;)